# calculating the Riemann integral of a function defined on an interval that's open one end.

Tags: integration

This is an additional exercise regarding the Riemann integral of $g:[0,1] \to (0,1)$ defined by:
$$g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
 1 & \text{if } 0< x \le 1, \\
 0 & \text{if } x = 0.
\end{cases}$$
I believe the integral doesn't exist but don't know how to show it, or if it does exist how to calculate it.

Comment: And $g(x)=0$ otherwise ?

Comment: sorry, I've corrected it. I have just started latex, so this is the best I could do.

Comment: @Sam.S: I think I just tromped on your edit. Can you please re-do?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the definition of the Riemann integral?

Comment: I have. My confusion lies with the fact that g(x) is defined on (0,1] as 1.  since a partition of I is a collection of nonempty intervals {I1, . . . , In} of almost-disjoint, nonempty closed intervals whose union is I, what partition would you consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Choose a partition all of whose intervals are of length $< \delta$. Depending on which point you pick for evaluation, the first interval contributes either $0$ or a value $< \delta$ to the sum. The sum of the remaining intervals will be $> 1 - \delta$.

What happens as $\delta \to 0$?